# How to allow percentage symbol in String format to get search results?

Tags: java

I am trying to get search results. If the search keyword is given with percentage symbol , it doesn't give results(the product has % in its name). It accepts only keywords without percentage symbol.

Search Keyword for which we get results: 
`Blue Band Koken & Opkloppen 31 Lactosevrij 1L` corresponds to 
`?q=Blue+Band+Koken+%26+Opkloppen+31+Lactosevrij+1L&xyz` format in url

Search Keyword for which I am not getting results: 
`Blue Band Koken & Opkloppen 31% Lactosevrij 1L` corresponds to
`?q=Blue+Band+Koken+%26+Opkloppen+31%25+Lactosevrij+1L&xyz`  format in url

Actual product name:`Blue Band Koken & Opkloppen 31% Lactosevrij 1L`
Decoder is unable decode for %. Hence getting error for below code:

Java Code:

```
public static String getEncodedParam(String string) {
 if (StringUtils.isBlank(string)) {
  return Constants.Strings.EMPTY;
 }

 String encodedString = string;
 try {
  if (string.equals(URLDecoder.decode(string, Constants.Encoding.UTF8))) {
   encodedString = URLEncoder.encode(string, Constants.Encoding.UTF8);
  }
 } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument is not in a correct state.");
 }
 return encodedString;
}
```

Comment: You need to urlencode those query parameters

Answer (score 1):

You have to URL-encode text that goes in a query string. One way to do it in Java is to use one of [`URLEncoder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html)'s `encode` methods.

For instance:

```
String search = "Blue Band Koken & Opkloppen 31% Lactosevrij 1L";
String query = "?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(search, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Updated the getSearchQuery() code[Refer the updated code above] as per suggestion but still getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: " L"
 at java.net.URLDecoder.decode(Unknown Source)

Comment: @RashmiKs - `URLEncoder.encode` won't produce the string you quoted there. It will replace spaces with `+`. If you encoded the string, and now you're receiving it at the other end and it has a space in it, something has already decoded that string for you. Example: https://ideone.com/UbyqhN

Comment: Updated the code where I am getting error with decoder. Whenever the keyword with % is given, it fails with the error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URLDecoder: Illegal hex characters in escape (%) pattern - For input string: " L" at java.net.URLDecoder.decode

Comment: @RashmiKs - Again, clearly something is decoding it *for you*. So don't use `decode` on it.

Comment: This is the existing code. I debugged and found out , this is the place where it fails and gives decoding error. It works fine if the keyword('string' in code) does not have '%' symbol in it .

Comment: @RashmiKs - It seems like you're not really getting my comments above. I'm not quite sure how to put it differently.

Comment: As per your suggestion, it works fine if Decoder is removed from here.